# RGenerator of ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java, android

So here is my code so far:

```
// Read Text File entitled wordsEn.txt 
        public String readFromFile() {
            String words = "";
            // Array List That Words being added to
            ArrayList<String> wordLineArray = new ArrayList<String>();

            try { 
                InputStream inputstream = openFileInput("wordsEn.txt");
                if (inputstream != null) {
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    String receiveString = "";
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                        wordLineArray.add(receiveString);
                        stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                    }
                    inputstream.close();
                    words = stringBuilder.toString();
                }

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
            }

            return words;
          //R Generator for Strings in wordLineArray 

            //String RandomWord = wordLineArray[rgenerator.
        }       

}
```

I want a random string selected from worldLineArray and stored into a String called RandomWord. I then want this RandomWord to be shown in a text view. My textview id is : testview1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Random` class to generate random number and then select element from arrayList like below :

```
Random random= new Random();
String random = wordLineArray.get(random.nextInt(wordLineArray.size()));
```

Comment: I am not fond with Collections.shuffle. Could you refresh my memory on a possible way to use it?

Comment: u can shuffle the collection with it,After that you need to select the element.Otherwise use Random class to select random element

Comment: I get an error from using nextInt. Also what is "list" referring to.

Comment: Alright. NextInt says its undefined. Is it because it is a string?

Comment: nextInt is a random method which will return the number between 0 and size of wordLineArray

Comment: Yes but I cannot use the code because its giving me an error.

Comment: NextInt is undefined because of String

Comment: you are passing string in random.nextInt() method ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.Random` to generate a random number between 0 and your `wordLineArray.size() - 1` and then use this number as index to pick the word from your `wordLineArray` to show in text view.